How to access controls inside a ListBoxItem?
I have a Listbox that each ListBoxItem is made of: a CheckBox, a TextBox and two ComboBoxes.
I'm populating the ComboBoxes with the code behind as each represent different attributes.
The ListBox is initialized at the begining from a data base.
The goal of the application is to allow users to change ElementType and ElementGroup from
ComboBoxes value, and if the CheckBox is checked the database will be updated according to
the new values.
I do not know how to access the ComboBoxes inside ListBoxItem (ElementData) and their values
(line 67 in .cs), where for now I'm just trying to pull those values in a StringBuilder to
visualy check the code.
Help greatly appreaciated!
Thank you.
Below is the .xml and the .cs

<Window x:Class="ListBoxTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title=" ListBox with CheckBoxes and ComboBoxes" Height="220" Width="600">
    <Grid Background="#FFF2FFCD">
        <StackPanel Margin="25">
            <ListBox x:Name="listBoxElements" SelectionMode="Multiple" AlternationCount="2" Width="500" SelectionChanged="listBoxElements_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <CheckBox Margin="2,2,2,2" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="   Type:   "></TextBlock>
                            <ComboBox  Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementTypeSource, Mode=OneWay}"></ComboBox>
                            <TextBlock Text="   Group   "></TextBlock>
                            <ComboBox  Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementGroupSource, Mode=OneWay}"></ComboBox>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ListBoxTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Element
        {
            public string ElementName { get; set; }
        }
        public class ElementData
        {
            public string ElementName { get; set; }
            private static readonly List<string> elementType;
            private static readonly List<string> elementGroup;
            static ElementData()
            {
                elementType = new List<string>();
                elementType.Add("Type A");
                elementType.Add("Type B");
                elementGroup = new List<string>();
                elementGroup.Add("Group A");
                elementGroup.Add("Group B");
                elementGroup.Add("Group C");
                elementGroup.Add("Group D");
            }
            public IEnumerable<string> ElementTypeSource => elementType;
            public IEnumerable<string> ElementGroupSource => elementGroup;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.listBoxElements.ItemsSource = new List<ElementData>
                {
                    new ElementData {ElementName = "Element 01"},
                    new ElementData {ElementName = "Element 02"},
                    new ElementData {ElementName = "Element 03"},
                    new ElementData {ElementName = "Element 04"},
                    new ElementData {ElementName = "Element 05"}
                };
        }

        StringBuilder sbSelectedListBoxItemData = new StringBuilder();
        private void listBoxElements_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            sbSelectedListBoxItemData.Clear();
            foreach (ElementData ed in listBoxElements.SelectedItems)
            {
                sbSelectedListBoxItemData.AppendLine(listBoxElements.Items.IndexOf(ed).ToString());
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sbSelectedListBoxItemData.ToString(), "Selected Data");
        }
    }
}

